# Why is the date in datepicker angular showing the last day?

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker

I use datepicker c angular material. Here's the code:

```
<td [formGroup]="item">
 <div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
   <mat-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date" formControlName="date">
 </div>
</td>
```

Datapicker is in the form that sends it to the server when it is sent.

But the problem is that the values are transmitted over the last day.

For example, I chose `1/18/2018`, but sent to the server `2018-01-17T22: 00: 00.000Z`.

It's strange that the angular pipe for date converts the date correctly, but before displaying it, I have a request on the server for grouping by the month and the first day of the new month falls on the last day of the previous one.

Date I store in mongoose schema with type Date.

Maybe someone had a problem with this.

Thank you.

Comment: is it always this time: 22:00:00 on previous day?

Comment: Yes, it is always

Comment: Have a look at the timezones between the server and the client. They could be different. You probably need to handle your timestamps in something like UTC unix timestamp which is standard always, then display it in the appropriate timezone

Comment: Maybe, but if I read date value in browser I get before day

Comment: Three questions: (a) is it possible to your server to be in a different time zone from the client (world wide app) (b) is it necessary for the server to know the time in the client (I  mean, is the server telling other clients in different timezones the current time of the original client) (c) can you provide more details (concrete use case)? Maybe you don't need to mess with the datepicker at all...

Comment: a) server and client now work on my local machine. b) I don't have necessary to store time in database and server don't know client time. c) I use datepicker to store date for which the user makes statistics

Comment: So I think you have nothing to worry. As soon as you receive the answer from the server containing the utc date, just do new Date(JSON.parse(utcDateReceived)) and the browser will do the back conversion according to the timezone of the host system and the day will be correct again.

Comment: Yes, but before I sent date from server to client I $group my stats by month. For example  `2018-01-31T22: 00: 00.000Z` in browser it is 01.02 and in query response it is 31.01 and all stats from first February sum to January stats

Comment: Oh, I see... I have a system in java connected to a mongodb but I use SpringData to do all the necessary database operations and I think it deals with this kind of thing. Well, dispite the fact that this is not a datepicker issue, you can build a workaround adding/subtracting, in the client (using a custom date adapter)), your offset using javascript  Date object getTimezoneOffset() before sending it to the server to be saved in the database.

Comment: Or, if you don't care about time, just set the hours to 12h00.

Comment: Take a look in this sample DateAdapter (for brazilian portuguese) setting the time always to 12: https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-adapter-qsqyeq

Comment: Same problem, is there a reasonable fix yet?

Comment: I added solution in answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solve this problem by converting datepicker date value to UTC. Here is example:

```
const d = new Date(<DATE FROM FORM FIELD>);
const date = Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
```

Maybe it's not elegant way to fix it but help me

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by configuring Datepicker to use UTC dates. (It uses local time by default)
Just add some providers on your component declaration :

```
import {MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';

@Component({
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]},
    {provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: {useUtc: true}}
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the accepted answer, but a little less verbose and will keep the hours/minutes/seconds.

```
const dt = new Date(event.value);
const tz = dt.getTimezoneOffset();
const seconds = (dt.getTime() / 1000) - (tz * 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may resolve it like this :
For example, if your are getting date in -> **one_day_back_date_value**

```
var one_day_back_date_value = moment.tz(moment(date_value_from_backend), 0).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
date_value_from_backend = moment(one_day_back_date_value).toDate();
```

**Please note :** **moment** and **moment-timezone libraries** are must for this.
Include **moment** library above the moment-timezone library.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using moment or dont want to override complete date-datapter then you can override native-date-adapter

```
@Injectable({        providedIn: 'root' }) 
export class CustomDateAdapterService extends NativeDateAdapter {    
    public createDate(year: number, month: number, date: number): Date {
        const localDate = super.createDate(year, month, date);
        const offset = localDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
        return new Date(localDate.getTime() - offset); // utcDate
    } 
}
```

[gist here](https://gist.github.com/harishrathi/db24a7f1d427a8ca742bd344780680cc)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it resolved the issue and there is nothing to do with the datepicker

```
const d = new Date(fieldDate);
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset());
console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, I solved it by converting the date/time, before sending to the server, using:

Example: (UTC Brazil)
I typed "**15**/12/2020 **22:30**:00" and it sent: '2020-12-**16**T**01:30**:00.000Z'.

```
var date = new Date('2020-11-06T01:30:00.000Z');
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString());
```

See [Date.prototype.getUTCDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate)