# How can i avoid time zone issue when i pick date from date picker ( previous day ) value is being sent to the backend?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, angular5

I wanted to display time in the following format throughout the application

**Example: Jun 27, 2019**

So I didn't want to use moment.js since I use only one format and for implementing that i'm using like this

**custom MAT_DATE_FORMATS**

```
export const APP_DATE_FORMATS = {
    parse: {dateInput: {month: 'short', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric'}},
    display: {
        dateInput: {month: 'short', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric'},
        monthYearLabel: {year: 'numeric'}
    }
};
```

And add it to the providers

```
providers: [{
   provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: APP_DATE_FORMATS
}]
```

This is the stackblitz url for that https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formatted-datepicker

But my problem is when i'm selecting any date from datepicker ( previous day value) is being sent to the backend

So to avoid that we're adding 5.30 hrs in the backend.It's not the right way to implement like that

I don't want to convert date to utc on every post call. So, Is there any easier and better way to avoid this timezone issue which **can be implemented at one common place**?

Comment: can u please check this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224785/why-is-the-date-in-datepicker-angular-showing-the-last-day this may fix ur issue and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50743810/material-angular-6-datepicker-is-parsing-my-date-1-day-before

Comment: @Phani They're using moment.js !

Comment: yes internally thats why i commented 2 urls.But better use that package

Comment: Best would be save it as utc/gmt on your backend and covert it back to the local time on your application.

Comment: Thanks for the links but I don't want to convert on every post call too. I should be able to do somewhere common.