# matDatepicker is sending request 1 day before picked date

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular, I'm using matDatepicker, everything is working fine except that when I make a post request and check the headers of my request I find out that the date that was sent is 1 day before the date I picked, for example if I picked 01/08/2020 it sends 01/07/2020, and the date that gets sent is displayed as: 2020-01-07T22:00:00.000Z, I've searched everywhere about this issue but non is working in my case, I would really appreciate your help.

employee.component.html

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [ngModel]="hiringDate"
     class="form-control" formControlName="HiringDate">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
```

employee.component.ts

```
this.editProfessionalInfoForm = this.fb.group({
  HiringDate: new FormControl({value: '' }, [Validators.required])
})

onSubmit() {
this.submitted = true;
if (this.editEmployeeForm.invalid) {
  this.loading = false;
  return;
}
this.restService.AddPersonalInfo(this.editEmployeeForm.value, 
this.urlId).subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.loading = false;
  this.translate.get('alert.savedSuccess').subscribe((res: string) => {
    this.toastr.success(res);
  });
})
}
```

Comment: Your ts snippet is missing ;)

Comment: oops I'm sorry, I have just updated my code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224785/why-is-the-date-in-datepicker-angular-showing-the-last-day see this

Comment: @NadeemShaikh I've tried it but still doesn't work

Comment: There should be some timezone issues. Please check the timezone carefully.

Comment: @jit Dhar, can you please tell me how can I adjsut this, my timezone is +02 GMT, so how can that be handled

Answer (score 0):

In your service.ts add at the end of the date type `toLocaleString()`

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to create in stackblitz like below one?

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/angular/eyyqbyvqnbg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-value-example.html